# Getting video dimensions at the time of upload (Django project)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

In a Django web app of mine, users upload videos that others can then view. Is there any way I can get the video height and/or width *at the time of video upload*? I can't do it in python since the video isn't yet residing on my server (and that's not an option in my particular set up anyway).

Note that there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856852/html5-video-height-and-width-through-javascript) on SO, but this doesn't deal with finding the width/height *when the file is being uploaded* via a Django form. And that's what I need. An answer containing an illustrative example would be nice.

Comment: you could try [this section of this library](https://github.com/buzz/mediainfo.js/blob/gh-pages/js/mediainfopage.js#L93) if you need to do it in the browser.

Comment: @YPCrumble: thanks for the hint.